# How can I have Pageant (Putty's SSH authentication agent) loads the private keys at start-up as well as the password?

Tags: putty

I would like Pageant to launch at start-up and load the appropriate keys as well as password without me having to be present to supply the password. Is there a way to achieve this on Windows XP, Windows 7 and Windows 2008 R2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must remove the password on the key for this to work.

Comment: Thanks but does that mean that Pageant doesn't support providing passwords in cleartext? There isn't any documentation that seems to suggest that.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: Yes, it doesn't support that, because it would defeat the whole point of having a password-encrypted key. You can remove the password and use the Windows built-in EFS encryption instead, though.